# Where do code generation sources (templates) go in maven's standard directory structure?

Tags: java, maven, templates, code-generation, fmpp

I have some java source files that need to be generated from templates and data. I'm using freemarker for this with fmpp and the maven exec plugin. It's working great, but I'm not sure where my templates should be put in the maven standard directory structure.

My generated files are going into the target directory under generated-sources - that's pretty obvious. What's not obvious is where the sources for these generated .java files should go. Right now, I've got them stored in src/main/templates (named *.java.ftl and in the proper package-defined sub-directory structure), along with the json data file and fmpp configuration file, but is there a better, more standard location for these types of files?